# Trying to call ShellExecute to run Mysql and a sql script

Tags: mysql, delphi, shellexecute

I've been trying to use ShellExecute from within a Delphi app to open Mysql and run a script.

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PWideChar(InpCommandProgram.text),
    PWideChar(commandline), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

InpCommandProgram.text = 'MYSQL'
commandline = '--user=root --password=password < C:/directory/filename.sql '
```

filename.sql has been stripped down to 'Create databasename'.

A command window opens briefly and scrolls some messages - too fast to read.
If I open a command window and enter the same program and commandline it works.
I can't see the error messages when it fails.

I'm running locally on a Windows 7 desktop. 
I tried directing output to a log file, but I don't even get the file in batch. I do get a log when it is successful interactively. I've tried all the tweaks I could think of.

Any ideas on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: add `> c:\mylog.txt` to the end of your command.  This will write the output to mylog.txt so you can see what's written to the screen before the command window closes.

Comment: @Toby In fact it won't because you need a command interpreter to organise the pipes. Which is the essence of the problem.

Comment: @Toby My original post noted that I had been redirecting to a log file without any results, although that was not in the example provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said it yourself when you said that the exact same command works at the command prompt. The difference there is the presence of a command interpreter, `cmd.exe`. What that does for you is create the pipe that pipes the input file into the MySQL process.

You have two obvious solutions to the problem:

1. Use `CreateProcess` to start the process and set up the pipes yourself. This is a little low level and involves a fair amount of Win32 boilerplate. It does make it a little simpler to block until the process has finished, should you need to do that.
2. Get `ShellExecute` to invoke `cmd.exe` and ask `cmd.exe` to run MySQL and sort out the pipes.

Option 2 is the simpler. It looks like this:

```
ShellExecute(
    0, 
    nil, 
    'cmd.exe', 
    '/c mysql --user=root --password=password < C:/directory/filename.sql',
    nil,
    SW_SHOW
);
```

The `/c` switch to `cmd.exe` tells to carry out the command and then terminate – which is just what you want here.

If you need to block your process until the MySQL process is done, then you can switch to `ShellExecuteEx`. That returns a process handle on which you can wait. Again it's a little harder to operate, but probably still easier than `CreateProcess` since that forces you to manages the pipe.

Comment: DAYS WORTH OF THANKS!!  That did what I need to do. Without the /c it just opened a command window. My mistake. Now I'll go back and restore all the simplifications, but this looks good. I guess the issue was that Mysql is a process, not an executable.

Comment: No that's not it. An executable file is needed in order to start a process. The issue is, as I said, that `mysql` can't do anything with your `<` pipe command. But `cmd.exe` can.