# Delphi + MySQL command line

Tags: mysql, delphi, cmd, shellexecute

I'm building a tool using Delphi and MySQL to restore a script generated with MySQLDump.
It was supposed to load and execute a SQL file and log any possible errors into a given output file.

I thought about execute the mysql command line and send command lines but i don't know if its possible ou how to do it since I just know how to call mysql using windows cmd and execute a single command line using ShellExecute or CreateProcess
I tried to do it with a single command line but it did'nt logged the errors properly

I tried this:
cmd /c mysql.exe --user root < "C:\restore.sql" > "C:\restore_log.txt"

the content of restore.sql was:
drop database test;

It does execute my script, but on the second attempt it should log "database doesn't exist" but restore_log.txt was empty

It would help if anyone could point the way to call mysql and send multiple lines OR a help with my cmd line to log properly
Anyone can help me?

Comment: you tried `--log-error=file_name`

Comment: on cmd it returns: unknown option '--log-error'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

digging more at stackoverflow I found previous answers that helped, the difference is that the output goes to a Memo that I can save to a file.
Thank you all for the help and the insights.

The answers can be found on the following links:

[Getting output from a shell/dos app into a Delphi app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119999/getting-output-from-a-shell-dos-app-into-a-delphi-app)

[How do I run a command-line program in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454501/how-do-i-run-a-command-line-program-in-delphi)

[Getting output from a shell/dos app into a Delphi app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119999/getting-output-from-a-shell-dos-app-into-a-delphi-app)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what components you've got available to connect to the MySQL db, but using TADOQuery to access SQL Server, I simply load up the queries into a TADOQuery's .SQL property and then call Open or ExecSQL. As long as it's just vanilla SQL that was generated by SQLDump, I'd guess that should work. It's worth a try anyway.

Comment: I was avoiding to use connection components.. I was trying to do it just calling mysqldump and mysql command lines, but I guess this is going to be the solution for now

Comment: Why insist on using the command-line tool? You have no control over a separate EXE launched as a child process. Either it succeeds or fails. It could even dump duplicate data into your DB.

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031225/trying-to-call-shellexecute-to-run-mysql-and-a-sql-script

Comment: almost that David Schwartz, this was just like my best attempt like i mentioned on the original question... the problem was that i couldn't retrieve error messages to a log file or screen